# Thread safe cached object for asp request

Tags: c#, asp.net, semaphore

First of all, I couldn't make the title more explanatory, I will try to lay out the problem then provide my solution for it

I'm implementing a backend in asp core for our game, we have few requests that are somewhat large, like requesting the items we provide in the store, every user starts the game loads the store info which makes a database trip to pull the entire store info, which RARELY change -less than once a month-, so we are making thousands of database trip that aren't needed.

on top of that we return timestamps for when was the last time an item image has changed, the images are stored in a blob which makes me query the blob for change date, which makes the request way costlier

so to solve all of this, I implemented a small class to cache the request until we need to update it,for this request and some others, but I'm not sure if I'm looking at this correctly

here is the base abstract class:

```
public abstract class CachedModel<T>
{
    protected T Model { get; set; }

    private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);

    protected abstract Task ThreadSafeUpdateAsync();
    protected abstract bool NeedsUpdate();

    public async Task<T> GetModel()
    {
        if (NeedsUpdate())
        {
            try
            {
                await semaphore.WaitAsync();
                if(NeedsUpdate()) // not sure if this is needed, can other threads enter here after the first one already updated the object?
                    await ThreadSafeUpdateAsync();
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphore.Release();
            }
        }
        return Model;
    }
}
```

and then I implement this class per request like this:

```
public class CachedStoreInfo : CachedModel<DesiredModel>
{
    protected override async Task ThreadSafeUpdateAsync()
    {
        // make the trip to db and Blob service
        Model = some result
    }

    protected override bool NeedsUpdate()
    {
        return someLogicToDecideIfNeedsUpdate;
    }
}
```

finally, in the asp controller all what I need to do is this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<DesiredModel> GetStoreInfo()
{
    return await cachedStoreInfo.GetModel();
}
```

Is this a proper implementation ? and is this even necessary or there is a smarter way to achieve this? getting the time stamps from the blob was the main reason I though about caching the result

Comment: Even though your data in the store changes once in a month, your application will certainly be restarted much often and with that your in-app cache will go away. Consider using Redis or similar database for external caching. For example https://redislabs.com/webinars/get-started-redis-microsoft-sql-server/,but just Google "redis as cache"

Comment: If you control the client and the server you could rely on eTag concept in your request options.

Comment: @KarelFrajták so? how often do you restart the servers? you will load the info once and cache it for days at least, as opposed to making blob and db trips thousands of times a minute!

Comment: @SqlSurfer I'm familiar with eTag concept, but how does this apply here? how can you make an eTag for sql table without making the trips to it

Comment: `can other threads enter here after the first one already updated the object` Yup they can. Your code could be optimized by returning the stale value while a background thread updates it, but since it almost never changes this is probably not needed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your implementation looks correct. Of course the instance of `CachedStoreInfo` should be a singleton in a required scope (as I understand in your case it should be a singleton in scope of application).

> can other threads enter here after the first one already updated the object?

As Kevin Gosse noted other threads can enter here. Your second check for `NeedsUpdate()` is a part of [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) pattern. And it might be a good optimization.

> and is this even necessary or there is a smarter way to achieve this?

As for me your implementation is minimalist and smart enough